# JDBC helper model

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I needed to create a basic JDBC helper class for our JDBC connection and wanted to know if my design is appropriate or needs cleans up?

---

Just a basic JDBC utility class which helps reduce the boilerplate code that JDBC has.

```
public class JDBCUtils {

    /**
     * Retrieves a connection from the given pool.
     *
     * @param reference Name of the pool from which the connection should be retrieved.
     *
     * @return the connection
     *
     * @throws SQLException on error
     */
    public static Connection getConnection(final String reference) throws SQLException {
        ComboPooledDataSource cpds = (ComboPooledDataSource) setConnection(reference);
        return cpds.getConnection();
    }

    /**
    * Sets up the connection by accessing an xml file that has all the necessary configurations for connecting to a specific database.
    */    
    private static DataSource setConnection(final String reference) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(reference)) {
            properties.loadFromXML(is);
        } catch (InvalidPropertiesFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        try {
            cpds.setDriverClass(properties.getProperty("driverClassName"));
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cpds.setJdbcUrl(properties.getProperty("jdbcUrl"));
        cpds.setUser(properties.getProperty("user"));
        cpds.setPassword(properties.getProperty("password"));

        return cpds;
    }

    /**
     * Closes this database Connection, ResultSet & Statement
     *
     * @param conn Connection
     * @param stmt Statement
     * @param rs ResultSet
     */
    public static void clearDBResources(Connection conn, Statement stmt, ResultSet rs) {
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LogUtils.warn("Unable to clear database resources", ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

        if (stmt != null) {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LogUtils.warn("Unable to clear database resources", ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                if (!conn.isClosed()) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LogUtils.warn("Unable to clear database resources", ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

This class is the generic data access object. It defines the basic interactions between all data objects and the data sources.

```
public abstract class GenericDAO {

    /**
     * This method returns a connection.
     *
     * @return the connection
     *
     * @throws SQLException on error
     */
    protected final Connection getConnection(String baseUrl) throws SQLException {
        if (!baseUrl.isEmpty() && baseUrl.contains("www") || baseUrl.contains("web")) {
            return JDBCUtils.getConnection(getPreProdDataSourceName());
        } else {
            return JDBCUtils.getConnection(getQam1DataSourceName());
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the data source name.
     *
     * @return data source name String
     */
    protected abstract String getQam1DataSourceName();

    /**
     * This method returns the data source name.
     *
     * @return data source name String
     */
    protected abstract String getPreProdDataSourceName();
}
```

---

This class is the class that points to a specific database, in this case it points to the QA database. There are more classes like this but they follow the same pattern.

```
public class QaDAO extends GenericDAO {

    /**
     * This method returns the data source name.
     *
     * @return data source name String
     */
    protected String getQam1DataSourceName() {
        return DataSourceConfig.getQam1DataSource();
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the data source name.
     *
     * @return data source name String
     */
    protected String getPreProdDataSourceName() {
        return DataSourceConfig.getQac1DataSource();
    }
}
```

---

This class points to the path to the xml that has all the necessary configurations needed to establish a connection.

```
public class DataSourceConfig {    

    private static final String QAM1_DATA_SOURCE = "src/main/java/com/qam1.xml";

    private static final String QAC1_DATA_SOURCE = "src/main/java/com/qas1.xml";

    public static String getQac1DataSource() {
        return QAC1_DATA_SOURCE;
    }

    public static String getQam1DataSource() {
        return QAM1_DATA_SOURCE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `e.printStackTrace();`

Catching exception just to do that is plain wrong. If you cannot handle it then just do not catch it. Also `e.printStackTrace();` is not suitable for logging exceptions. If you just want to log it use a proper logger.

2. `ComboPooledDataSource cpds = (ComboPooledDataSource) setConnection(reference);`

There is absolutely no need to downcast to a specific subclass. What will happen if if `setConnection()` does not return a `ComboPooledDataSource` ?

3. `clearDBResources()`

this method seems pretty useless to me. One should use a try-finally or try-with-resources to guarantee that the resources will be closed.

4. The DAO itself is not a dao. A true dao hides the implementation details, but yours just exposes everything.
5. It's not clear if this is a webapp, but if it is you should let the container manage the datasource, not the application.

Comment: For 1. I will handle it better. I just did a e.printStackTrace() just for POC purposes. 
2. I did that because the `setConnection()` method returns a datasource so I had to cast the c3p0 datasource.
3. K, will implement try with resources.
4. Yea, my mistake. I changed the title to say helper JDBC class. Not really DAO pattern.
5. It is not an application. I needed to create this for running automated test scripts via selenium.

Comment: You still don;t need to downcast to `ComboPooledDataSource`. You wan't to work with the abstraction, not the concrete implementation. But if you want the concrete implementation, then make it explicit by changing the method signature to return `ComboPooledDataSource` instead of the abstraction